# Why do we have to specify server-side encryption in the http header?

Tags: amazon-s3, http-headers

This article in the AWS Developer Blog describes how to generate pre-signed urls for S3 files that will be encrypted on the server side: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/generating-amazon-s3-pre-signed-urls-with-sse-kms-part-2/ . The part that describes how to generate a url makes sense, but then the article goes on to describe how to use the url in a put request, and it says that, in addition to the generated url, one must add to the http request a header specifying the encryption algorithm. Why is this necessary when the encryption algorithm was included in the url's generation?

```
// Generate a pre-signed PUT URL for use with SSE-KMS
GeneratePresignedUrlRequest genreq = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(
    myExistingBucket, myKey, HttpMethod.PUT)
    .withSSEAlgorithm(SSEAlgorithm.KMS.getAlgorithm());

...

HttpPut putreq = new HttpPut(URI.create(puturl.toExternalForm()));
putreq.addHeader(new BasicHeader(Headers.SERVER_SIDE_ENCRYPTION,
    SSEAlgorithm.KMS.getAlgorithm()));
```

I ask in part due to curiosity but also because the code that has to execute the put request in my case is running on a different machine from the one that generates the url. I won't go into the details, but it's a real hassle to make sure that the header that one machine generates matches the url that the other machine generates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how "clear" the justification is, but my assumption is that the encryption parameters are required to be sent as headers in order to keep them from appearing in logs that log the query string.

> Why is this necessary when the encryption algorithm was included in the url's generation

This aspect is easier to answer.  A signed request is a way of proving to the system that someone in possession of your access-key-secret authorized this exact, specific request, down to the last byte.  Change *anything* about the request that was included in the signature generation, and you have invalidated the signature, because now the request differs from what was authorized.

When S3 receives your request, it looks up your secret key and does exactly what your local code does... it signs the request it received and checks whether its generated signature matches the one you supplied.

A common misconception is that signed URLs are generated by the service, but they aren't.  Signed URLs are generated entirely locally.  The algorithm is not computationally-feasible to reverse-engineer, and for any given request, there is exactly 1 possible valid signature.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the information about encryption doesn't get included in the presigned url. I'm guessing the only reason it's included in the GeneratePresignedUrlRequest is for generating a hash that's checked for authentication. After reading up on the question of when to use url parameters vs custom headers, I have to wonder if there is any clear justification for S3's using custom headers instead of url parameters here. As mentioned in the original question, having to include these headers makes using this API difficult. I wouldn't have this problem if url parameters were used instead. Any comments on the matter would be appreciated.